# Qt Gui and Phantom Omni

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm working with an Haptic Device (" Phantom Omni"), and i'm creating a GUI, this gui has some headers and source files from the haptic device. I've already included them, but I have also include the libraries. I've tried all the several ways that I found on internet, but when I try to build the project it returns me error about LNK 2019 and LNK 2001.
I've checked also the Makefile that the qMake generates, and into this file there are the paths and libraries that i would to add, but I don't know why, I have always the some error.

The .pro file:

```
#LIBS += -L"C:\\Folder\\Folder2\\LibFolder" -lextlib.lib


QT       += core gui
CONFIG += console

QT += gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = GUI_TeleManipulation
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        gui_telemanipulation.cpp \
    debug/moc_gui_telemanipulation.cpp \
    src/Client.cpp \
    src/PHANToM.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hdu.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hduAfx.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hduDecompose.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hduError.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hduHapticDevice.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hduLine.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hduLineSegment.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hduMatrix.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hduPlane.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hduQuaternion.cpp \
    src/HDU/src/hduRecord.cpp \
    src/hd.cpp

HEADERS  += gui_telemanipulation.h \
    ui_gui_telemanipulation.h \
    include/Client.hpp \
    include/matrix.h \
    include/Packet.hpp \
    include/PHANToM.h \
    include/HD/hd.h \
    include/HD/hdCompilerConfig.h \
    include/HD/hdDefines.h \
    include/HD/hdDevice.h \
    include/HD/hdExport.h \
    include/HD/hdScheduler.h \
    include/HDU/hdu.h \
    include/HDU/hduBoundBox.h \
    include/HDU/hduError.h \
    include/HDU/hduGenericMatrix.h \
    include/HDU/hduHapticDevice.h \
    include/HDU/hduLine.h \
    include/HDU/hduLineSegment.h \
    include/HDU/hduMath.h \
    include/HDU/hduMatrix.h \
    include/HDU/hduPlane.h \
    include/HDU/hduQuaternion.h \
    include/HDU/hduRecord.h \
    include/HDU/hduVector.h \
    src/HDU/src/hduAfx.h \
    src/HDU/src/hduDecompose.h


FORMS    += gui_telemanipulation.ui

#LIBS += -L"C:\\Folder\\Folder2\\LibFolder" -lextlib.lib

LIBS += -L"lib/" -lhd
LIBS += -L"lib/" -lhdu
```

Comment: Please show your .pro file. Also tell where the libraries you need are located in the file system.

Comment: When I try the "several" ways, I choose the ones that work, so you see, it works for me. You must show relevant code (the `.pro`) file at least, otherwise how can we tell what you did wrong?

Comment: the libraries are into a folder called lib, inside the same folder of the file .pro.
I'm programming on Windows

Answer (score 0):

With static libraries, you should be able to use simply this:

```
LIBS += "C:/Folder/Folder2/LibFolder/extlib.lib"
```

This is assuming you are doing Windows-only project. Read [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) for more.

Comment: I did it but it returns me always the same link error